# Official Pi Keyboard repeating characters for 1,2,q,w,a,s,z,x

Tags: raspberry-pi-desktop

I just bought the official desktop kit of Raspberry Pi 4 with 4 GB ram.

press 1 - 12 getting printed
press 2 - 12 getting printed
press q - qw getting printed
press w - qw getting printed
press a - as getting printed
press a - as getting printed
press z - zx getting printed
press z - zx getting printed

Comment: Have you tested that keyboard in another computer. It sounds like it has a hardware fault.

Comment: Yes, the fact that these pairs of keys are A) Next to one another,  B) All grouped together, is probably not a coincidence.  That being the case, it's not a configuration or other software issue, there isn't much we can do for you here -- but welcome anyways, Chandan.  You should return the keyboard to the distributor.